# Can't get \fancyheadoffset to work

Tags: errors, header-footer, fancyhdr, calculations

I have loaded the `fancyhdr` package and I want to make the headers and footers wider (clamp them to the margin), so I inserted the following line after the package has loaded:

`\fancyheadoffset[LE,RO]{\marginparsep + \marginparwidth}`

This is from an example in the document [Page layout in LaTeX](ftp://www.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex2e/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf). But when I try to compile I get the following error:

`Missing number, treated as zero`

two times, and equally many plus signs in my document. When I enter `\marginparsep` in the body text, I also found that this gave the same error message. Why is it missing? I need it! :P

Comment: If you look closely, the line above the one you mention from the document you cite is precisely `\usepackage{calc}`. It's always best to try making a minimal example: very often this allows to sort out the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Load the [`calc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/calc) package:

   ```
   \usepackage{calc}
   \fancyheadoffset[LE,RO]{\marginparsep + \marginparwidth}
   ```
2. Use the e-TeX `\dimexpr`:

   ```
   \fancyheadoffset[LE,RO]{\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}
   ```